# Specify line breaks in chapter headers

Tags: header-footer, chapters, ubuntu

I created my own .cls file for my thesis and I'm getting an error message when I specify line breaks in my chapter titles

Here is the section in the file that defines the chapter heading:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%   Chapter heading font size
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{sectsty}

\chapternumberfont{\normalsize} 
\chaptertitlefont{\normalsize}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%   Title spacing
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage{titlesec} % Adjust title headers

% Reduce spacing after section/subsection/subsubsections
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

% Single spaced headers
\titleformat{\chapter}      % command
    [display]               % shape
    {\color{UOFURED}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries\doublespacing}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Large\thechapter}
    {0pt}                   % separations
    {\MakeUppercase}        % before
    []              % After (leave blank)

%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\huge\bfseries\singlespacing}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{40pt}{\huge}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\centering\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

Here is how I define a chapter so that the text is all caps

```
\chapter{\uppercase{Chapter title goes here}}
```

However, my University requires that long chapter titles need to be inverted pyramids.  I've read you can do this by specifying line breaks like this:

```
\chapter[This is a really long title that needs to be wrapped as an inverted pyramid]{This is a really long title that \\ needs to be wrapped as an \\ inverted pyramid}
```

I am getting an error message after compiling in ubuntu that says:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\reserved@a #1#2->\let #1#2\reserved@a

l.8 ...ds to be wrapped as an \\ inverted pyramid}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

would anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try with `\protect\\ `? – Ivan 17 mins ago   Delete

Comment: I just made that change and it appears to be working.  Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments.  Simply adding `\protect\\` inside the `\chapter` call worked.